# Can't access a remote API on release apk, app has internet permission

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions, http-get

The issue is with an `http.get` request, for some reason I can't access my API on release versions, but it runs smoothly in debug mode.

I already gave internet permission on android/app/AndroidManifest.xml, and I already tested the permission by using Image.network, and I got the image.

Comment: We need some code to see what is wrong. However ‘localhost’ Is a common problem because it tries to use ip6 rather than ip4. If you are using localhost, try 127.0.0.1

Comment: There will be some log on your logcat

Comment: I fix this issue, It's because I edit my packages name, I think there's some problem on there. I build new project and it run smoothly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this issue, It's because I edit my packages name, I think there's some problem on there. I build new project and it run smoothly

Answer (score 2):

It's because by default http requests are disabled is release mode. Use the following code to enable it.

```
<manifest 
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"> 
... 
</application>
```

usesCleartextTraffic="true" is the key setting here.

I was fortunate enough to find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24408#issuecomment-490368508)